# How can I prove that if a domain $R$ is an injective module, then $R$ is a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, string-theory

What are the similarities between a field and a projective module that can support my question?

Comment: I'm guessing you mean projective by objective, and field by body.  
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93539/if-r-is-an-integral-domain-and-every-r-module-is-projective-must-r-be-a

Comment: In fact, I refer to the injection modules

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213275/injective-integral-domains-are-fields